# TP-Link Access Control targets

Tags: router, firewall, home-networking, access-control

I want to configure an access control rule target on my TP-Link router (Archer C-7). I want a target I can use to blocks access to any Internet IP. I thought I could tell it "block IP address range 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255. However, I get errors like:

```
Error code: 29013
Wrong End IP Address.
```

I can't figure out what I should use as the IP address range. Here is a screenshot of the configuration UI:

[image: Router config]

1. What is the correct IP range to represent all Internet addresses?
2. Why is the correct answer not 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is often a difference between "the correct answer" and "the answer that the router firmware's developers think is correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the ranges individually.

Class-A - (1.0.0.0 - 126.255.255.255)

Class-B - (128.0.0.0 - 191.255.255.255)

Class-C - (192.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255)

Class-D - (224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255) reserved

Class-E - (240.0.0.0 - 254.255.255.255) reserved

You shouldn't be seeing any class A, B, or C private range addresses showing up from the internet, but unfortunately you may also have to block those addresses depending on your isp. (Every once and a while I have private addresses come up in my firewall logs) which really should never happen.

You maybe also be able to enter the total range as:
1.0.0.0 - 254.255.255.255 (A through D).
Or.
1.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255 (A through C)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that TP-Link provides a target called "Any". That is what I ended up using.

Comment: Just to clarify. The "Any Host" target, block all the internet addresses but allow LAN  access.

Comment: I really enjoy my tp-link, but this situation with access control is really bad. An example of how not to do things.